# Color Gradient for Several Plots

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

I have a `Table` of `Sin[nx]` functions where `n` is an integer. Now my issue is that I have been searching a way to make the plots look like a gradient of a color because if I just use the available options for `PlotStyle` it is hard to distinguish each plot.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Sin[n x], {n, 1, 3, 1}]], {x, -1, 10}, AxesStyle -> {Thick, 18}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, "BlueGreenYellow"}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

An example is shown above where I just plotted three `Sin[nx]`. The colors shown there are very random, I would like say a dark color red is the first plot, a lighter red is the second plot, and so on.

Another option I would like is say a gradient from red to blue, so that the evolution of the plots can be seen through the gradient of the color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question addresses [`PlotTheme`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html).

This is how default [`PlotTheme`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html) looks:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 5}]], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: default plottheme]

It is `"PastelColor"`. No `Plot` without [`PlotTheme`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html).

Very much contrasting is:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 5}]], {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotTheme -> "GrayColor"]
```

[image: GrayColor]

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 5}]], {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotTheme -> "CoolColor"]
```

[image: "CoolColor"]

Like in the question the options can be overwritten and replace in putting them explicit in the options list and give them the desired value.

Your question addresses too [`PlotStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle.html). Then a solution will be

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 3}], {x, 0, 15}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Darker@Orange, Orange, Lighter@Orange}]
```

[image: PlotStyle with Orange]
But that there only three lightnesses built in.

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 5}], {x, 0, 15}, 
 PlotStyle -> Table[Darker[Blue, i/5], {i, 1, 5}]]
```

[image]
This in not so high in contrast but step in `Darker` of the color `Blue`.
Same with Lighter:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 5}], {x, 0, 15}, 
 PlotStyle -> Table[Lighter[Blue, i/7.5], {i, 1, 5}]]
```

[image: Lighter]
Mathematica knows since 12 a lot of important colors: [`Color`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/entity/Color.html).

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 5}], {x, 0, 15}, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Table[Lighter[Interpreter["Color"]["HTML green"], i/7.5], {i, 1, 
    5}], AxesStyle -> {Thick, 18}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Interpreter["Color"]["HTML green"]]
You may use [`Blend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blend.html):

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 5}], {x, 0, 15}, 
 PlotStyle -> Table[Blend[{Red, Blue}, x], {x, 0, 1, 1/5}], 
 AxesStyle -> {Thick, 18}, PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Blend between Red and Blue]
References on [`Blend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blend.html) spend ideas for many more possibilities.

Comment: The default theme is _not_ `"PastelColor"`. It is `ColorData[97]` applied to the `PlotStyle`.

Answer (score 3):

This?

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Sin[n x], {n, 1, 3, 1}]], {x, -1, 10}, 
 AxesStyle -> {Thick, 18}, 
 PlotStyle -> (Blend[{Red, White}, #] & /@ Subdivide[0, 1, 3]), 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```